# Get value from _internallinkedhashmap Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

in my Flutter App I have a var like this
[image]

How can I check if in the first row there is "data" or "testo" and so on?
And then how can I read the value of the row? (in this case "10/10/2019")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var data =item['diario']['elementi'] as Map;
print(data.keys.first);
print(data.values.first)
print(data.keys);
print(data.values);

// data.keys.first = data
// data.values.first= 10/10/2019
// data.keys = (data,testo,acquisto,ora)
// data.values=(10/10/2019,Oggi giornata molto interessante,......)
```

**_internallinkedhashmap** consists of key value pair. So to extract a keys i.e headings (data, testo, acquisto, ora) in above case you can use `.key` and for corresponding value list that each heading contains you can use `.value` (10/10/2019, Oggi giornata molto interessante,......) in above case.
 If you want to extract first item you can use `data.keys.first`